How to force Jetpack compose LazyHorizontalGrid to fill row by row
I have a HorizontalGridLayout with 2 rows. I receive a variable number of items to fill it. When I receive a large number of items everithing is fine. But the problems arise when I have few items.
I'm forcing the grid to have only one line when I have fewer than 6 items and that works well also. But if I have 6 I would want for the first line to fill up and the 6 item to apear bellow.
I know this behaviour sounds more like a Flow Layout. But I also need it to have horizontal scrolling for the case when I have a lot of items, and I can't have more than 2 lines.
Here is a representation of what I'm obtaining:

And what I'm trying to achieve:

Here is my code for the horizontal grid:
@Composable
fun HorizontalGridLayout(
    rowNumber: Int,
    columnList: List<@Composable (ColumnScope.() -> Unit)>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    LazyHorizontalGrid(
        modifier = modifier,
        rows = GridCells.Fixed(rowNumber),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(spacerSize),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(spacerSize)
    ) {
        repeat(rowNumber) {
            item {
                Spacer(Modifier.width(horizontalSpacing))
            }
        }
        items(
            count = columnList.size,
            key = {
                columnList[it].hashCode()
            }, itemContent = { column ->
                Column(
                    content = columnList[column]
                )
                if (column < columnList.size - 1) {
                    Spacer(Modifier.width(spacerSize))
                }
            }
        )
        repeat(rowNumber) {
            item {
                Spacer(Modifier.width(horizontalSpacing))
            }
        }
    }
}


Following this logic, where and in which order should be the 11th, 12th and 13th element placed (when scrolled into view)? All of them in the first row, following the 5th element? Please [edit] to provide a numbering scheme for each visible element and all invisible elements until the pattern repeats. As it is now it is unclear what you want to achieve.

Instead of starting a bounty you should improve the question to be clear about what you want to achieve. You can start by addressing my first comment.
